# - Python Issue: Working with an Array key-value inside a While statement, is overwritting the content even if different names are detected

Tags: python, arrays, arraylist, while-loop, key-value

***Explanation:***

*I'm trying to do a Progress bar, where you can control it by updating some values on an Excel, and it shows the changes live in a .svg file.*

**Issue:**

I've a loop that can repeat itself sometimes, but the names of the Listed key-value inside the Array are changed between 2 options.

The issue is that, even if I've those 2 options separately, and even with the Print showing the values correctly, the data stored inside is in the same key-value as the 1st time the Loop entered the method.

Here is where I declare the ArrayList, among some others properties:

```
class RangeBar(GraphicsPort):
    _opacity = {
        "firstPhase": 1,
        "thirdPhase": 1
    }
```

Some code of the main() where the While statement is working:

```
        if (rb._empty["firstPhase"] == False):
            print("Start Phase 1 Loop")
            rb.partialPhase(False, "firstPhase")
            print("Exit Phase 1 Loop")
        if (rb._empty["fillPhase"] == False):
            print("Start Phase 2 Loop")
            rb.fillPhase(False, "fillPhase")
            print("Exit Phase 2 Loop")
        if (rb._empty["thirdPhase"] == False):
            print("Start Phase 3 Loop")
            rb.partialPhase(False, "thirdPhase")
            print("Exit Phase 3 Loop")
```

Code of the partialPhase method (the one where this happens):

```
def partialPhase(self, baseCellModified, phase):
    if (baseCellModified != False):
        self.setValue(baseCellModified)
        self._opacity[phase] = baseCellModified / 100
        self.sheet_action("update_sheet_data",cell="C3",number=100)
    if (phase == "firstPhase"):
        self.setValue(86.9)
    if (phase == "thirdPhase"):
        self.setValue(12.9)
    print("New opacity for 'phase':",phase,"from: 'self._opacity[phase]':", self._opacity[phase])
    self.sheet_action("opacity_update", opacity=str(self._opacity[phase]))
    self.sheet_action("update_sheet_data",cell="D3",number=self.getValue())
    svg = str(self.__utils)
    text_file = open("./1.svg", "w")
    text_file.write(svg)
    text_file.close()
    timeToAction = self.sheet_action("get_sheet_data", type="numb", cell="F3") * 60
    time.sleep(timeToAction)

    while self._opacity[phase] > 0:
        timeToAction = self.sheet_action("get_sheet_data", type="numb", cell="F3") * 60
        changeCell = self.sheet_action("get_sheet_data", type="numb", cell="E3")
        action = self.identifyAction("G3")
        if (action == "decrement"):
            self._opacity[phase] -= (changeCell / 8)
            print("'phase' is showing opacity of:", phase)
            print("'self._opacity[phase]' is showing:", self._opacity[phase])
        if (action == "increment"):
            self._opacity[phase] += (changeCell / 8)
        if self._opacity[phase] < 0:
            print("Entering opacity minor to 0")
            print("'phase' is showing opacity of:", phase)
            print("'self._opacity[phase]' is showing:", self._opacity[phase])
            self._opacity[phase] = 0
            self._empty[phase] = True
            if (phase == "thirdPhase"):
                self._critical = True 
        self.sheet_action("opacity_update", opacity=str(self._opacity[phase]))
        self.sheet_action("update_sheet_data",cell="D3",number=self.getValue())
        svg = str(self.__utils)
        text_file = open("./1.svg", "w")
        text_file.write(str(self.__utils))
        text_file.close()
        time.sleep(timeToAction)
```

.svg to start from:

[image]

some prints from 1st phase:

[image]

After setting it to 0

[image]

After exiting Phase 2 (fill empty)

[image]

Now it happens the error, the Opacity of "firstPhase" turned 1, and it looks like this:

[image]

And now the code interacts with the 'firstPhase' all time, even if 'thirdPhase' appears in the prints, as the 'phase' it's getting this value.

[image]

Until it disappears again:

[image]

Thanks for take your time to read me, and sorry for the large text .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a Newbie miss that I didn't even noticed.

The code I passed was good, but a method I was calling, was hardcoded from previous tests, and I didn't noticed it.

The phase which I wanted to change, was "thirdPhase" all the time, so it was constantly changing the opacity of the thirdPhase, even if I passed a different opacity, the phase remained the same.

I'm sorry if I wasted someone time on this  and thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the while loop declare _opacity = {}, we need to make that empty, else for each run it adds the value in it.

Comment: I tried, but it throws an error when is looking for the key:vale, cuz of no values in it.
I also tried to add with the key:value when exiting the method (so, when the new one starts, it's everything declared)
But still throwing same error, adding the value to self._opacity["firstPhase"] even if it detects the "thirdPhase" as a return.

I'm thinking that maybe is something that Python didn't contemplated, or idk .

Comment: The example of what I'm talking about: `if (rb._empty["firstPhase"] == False):
                rb.partialPhase(False, "firstPhase")
                rb._opacity = {"firstPhase": 0, "thirdPhase": 1}
            if (rb._empty["fillPhase"] == False):
                rb.fillPhase(False, "fillPhase")
            if (rb._empty["thirdPhase"] == False):
                rb.partialPhase(False, "thirdPhase")
                rb._opacity = {"firstPhase": 0, "thirdPhase": 0}`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).